# Subtract column data from two unrelated tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: snapshot of the database diagram]

> This is the database diagram I want to determine the blood that's remaining in each bank this achieved by subtracting `[Amount Accepted]` from `[Amount Donated]`
>
> I have tried to make selections of blood drawn into banks and blood withdrawn from banks but my problem is I can't subtract the two columns `[blood drawn]` and `[blood withdrawn]` because they are in tables which are not related

[image: snapshot of the selections]

Comment: Don't use links to pictures (or pictures) , show data and query in ascii.

Comment: Please don't tag multiple RDBMS when your question is only related to one. When posting code, make sure you provide it as `text`. Images of code are very poorly received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like following.

```
SELECT *, [blood drawn(ml)]-[blood withdrawn(ml)]
FROM
(
 <YOUR QUERY1>
)A
INNER JOIN
(
 <YOUR QUERY2>
)B
ON A.[Blood Bank Name]= B.[Blood Bank Name]
```

Comment: Thank you i am sorry i am still new here

Answer (score 0):

Wrap both Selects in Derived Tables or Common Table Expressions and join them, e.g.

```
with donated as
 ( select ...
 )
, accepted as
 ( select ...
 )
select ...
from donated as a
join accepted as a 
  on a.[blood bank name] = d..[blood bank name]
```

Answer (score 0):

Note the '-' before `[Amount Accepted]` is the key.

```
SELECT x.[Blood Bank Name], SUM(x.[Net Amount])
FROM 
(
    SELECT [Blood Bank Name],  [Amount Donated] AS [Net Amount] 
    FROM [Donation Record]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [Blood Bank Name], -[Amount Accepted] AS [Net Amount] 
    FROM [Transfusion Record]        
) x
GROUP BY x.[Blood Bank Name]
```